# Mobile accelerometer - Slow div on rotate

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, accelerometer, velocity

I'm using the following code to move a ball around the screen when my mobile phone is rotated:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Gyro_Ball</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="ball"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
if ( !window.requestAnimationFrame ) {

  window.requestAnimationFrame = ( function() {

    return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function( /* function FrameRequestCallback */ callback, /* DOMElement Element */ element ) {

        window.setTimeout( callback, 1000 / 60 );

      };

  } )();

}



var ball;
var w;
var h;

function init()
{
  ball = document.getElementById("ball");
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;

  ball.style.left = (w/2)-50+"px";
  ball.style.top = (h/2)-50+"px";
  ball.velocity = {x:0,y:0}
  ball.position = {x:0,y:0}

  if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {

    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event)
      {
        ball.velocity.y = Math.round(event.beta);
        ball.velocity.x = Math.round(event.gamma);
      }
    )
  };

  update();
}

function update()
{
  ball.position.x += ball.velocity.x;
  ball.position.y += ball.velocity.y;

  if(ball.position.x > (w-100) && ball.velocity.x > 0)
  {
    ball.position.x = w-100;
  }

  if(ball.position.x < 0 && ball.velocity.x < 0)
  {
    ball.position.x = 0;
  }

  if(ball.position.y > (h-100) && ball.velocity.y > 0)
  {
    ball.position.y = h-100;
  }

  if(ball.position.y < 0 && ball.velocity.y < 0)
  {
    ball.position.y = 0;
  }

  ball.style.top = ball.position.y + "px"
  ball.style.left = ball.position.x + "px"

  requestAnimationFrame(update);//KEEP ANIMATING
}
```

**CSS**
    body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #32c9d6;
    }

```
#ball
{
-webkit-transition: all;
transition: all;
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: white;
}
```

It works great! BUT I need to slow the ball down when I rotate my mobile....any ideas?

HERE IS A DEMO (Use Your mobile to view it):
http://inkfood.github.io/Gyro_Ball2/

JSFIDDLE (Use Your mobile to view it): 
https://jsfiddle.net/qq74w6a3/6/

I just need to slow that ball down when tilting left to right so it doesn't zoom across so fast...there must be a delay or acceleration or FPS I can use to slow it down?

Comment: Can you fix the javascript. Looks like the update function is not closed properly.

Comment: I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

I tried getting this to work on mobile, but I couldn't. But I did add a mouse event which uses the mouse delta to slow the ball.

I calculate how far the mouse is away from the ball center and then use that percentage to adjust the velocity. I think you could use this to find how far the ball center is from the oriented side. i.e. the bottom.

Run the embedded script and move your mouse around. The ball should slow as it gets closer to the mouse position.

```js
if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
    return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function( /* function FrameRequestCallback */ callback, /* DOMElement Element */ element) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
  })();
}

var ball;
var dbg;
var w;
var h;
var my = 0;
var mx = 0;

function update() {
  ball.position.x += ball.velocity.x;
  ball.position.y += ball.velocity.y;

  if (ball.position.x > (w - 100) && ball.velocity.x > 0) {
    ball.position.x = w - 100;
  }

  if (ball.position.x < 0 && ball.velocity.x < 0) {
    ball.position.x = 0;
  }

  if (ball.position.y > (h - 100) && ball.velocity.y > 0) {
    ball.position.y = h - 100;
  }

  if (ball.position.y < 0 && ball.velocity.y < 0) {
    ball.position.y = 0;
  }

  ball.style.top = ball.position.y + "px";
  ball.style.left = ball.position.x + "px";

  requestAnimationFrame(update); //KEEP ANIMATING
}

function init() {
  ball = document.getElementById("ball");
  dbg = document.getElementById("debug");
  w = window.innerWidth;
  h = window.innerHeight;
  ball.style.left = (w / 2) - 50 + "px";
  ball.style.top = (h / 2) - 50 + "px";
  ball.velocity = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  ball.position = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event) {
      ball.velocity.y = Math.round(event.beta);
      ball.velocity.x = Math.round(event.gamma);
    });
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
      my = event.clientY;
      mx = event.clientX;
    });
    window.setInterval(function() {
      var wy = window.outerHeight;
      var wx = window.outerWidth;
      var bcy = ball.position.y + 50; //ball center Y
      var bcx = ball.position.x + 50; // ball center X
      var dy = Math.round(((my - bcy) * 100 / wy) * 10000) / 10000;
      var dx = Math.round(((mx - bcx) * 100 / wx) * 10000) / 10000;
      ball.velocity.y = dy;
      ball.velocity.x = dx;
      dbg.innerHTML = 'deltaY:' + dy + ' deltaX:' + dx;
    }, 100);
  }
  update();
}

init();
```

```css
#ball {
  -webkit-transition: all;
  transition: all;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
#debug {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ball"></div>
<div id="debug">x:0 y:0</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I havent managed to try your code as of yet, but you mention mouse, there is no mouse on a mobile? The ball is meant to move on by phone orientation using the gyroscope and not touch, does your code take this into account?

Comment: Correct about the mouse. I couldn't get your code to work on mobile, so I implemented my code using mouse movements. The key is to show you the delta calculation. You should easily be able to swap out the mouse with your gyroscope input.

Comment: Ahh thank you for clarifying...would you be able to provide code that swaps out the mouse for gyroscope...apologies as i'm rather new to this.

Comment: Not without seeing a working copy of your mobile code. Like I said, I couldn't get it to work. Can you make a fiddle or CodePen of you code?

Comment: I've updated my question with those details plus more